# Get category id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to get category id from wp_terms where name is say "services".
I do so:

```
$myrows = $wpdb-> query("SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE name='services' " );
if(!$myrows){
echo "wrong".mysql_error();
}
else{
 echo $myrows ->ID;
 }
```

But it does not print anything. WHat is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do, but can you try this?

```
echo get_cat_ID('services');
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID